# Sql Server CE 2.0 RDA on IIS 7 and Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008, sql-server-ce

I am trying to get SQL server CE 2.0 RDA that was working on IIS6 (Server 2003) and Sql Server 2000 moved to a Windows 2008 server with IIS and SQL server 2008.

Is this something that is possible?  It seems that there is no fundamental reason that it would not.  The target database is not changed since the migration.

My first problem is that I do not seem to be able to get the Virtual Directory right.  Testing the URL causes a prompt for download.  This, of course, did not happen on the old installation.

Part of my problem is that I have no access to the source code of the client program.  About the only configuration I have is the ability to change the URL on the client.

Thanks, Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try the URL and it attempts to download the DLL, so IIS is not configured right as an application. It's thinking that you want to download this file and not to execute.

Try to install in this server or run the "Configure Web Synchronization Wizard" that it manages the IIS configuration for you.

And you can run the 3.5 version instead 2.0 in server, and clients can connect with previous version without issues. My configuration has a server with Windows Server 2003, SQL Server 2008 Express and Windows Compact 3.5 on IIS. The clients are Windows Mobile 6.x with SQL Mobile 2005.